# Scala: all substrings of length k

Tags: scala, apache-spark, functional-programming, mapreduce

I am totally new to scala and I am having trouble understanding how I can use functions like `map()` or `foreach()` to perform operations on strings.

In particular, I am trying to extract all unique contiguous substrings of length k from a string (called k-shingles). My function `kshingles(s: String, k: Int)` called on the string `"abcdab"` should return `Set("ab", "bc", "cd", "da")`.

How can I achieve that in scala? A bonus would be to do it in a way that it can be parallelized (e.g. using Spark)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`sliding`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.4/scala/collection/Iterator.html#sliding%5BB%3E:A%5D(size:Int,step:Int):Iterator.this.GroupedIterator%5BB%5D) is the method you are looking for. From `sliding` documentation:

> Groups elements in fixed size blocks by passing a "sliding window" over them (as opposed to partitioning them, as is done in `grouped`.) The "sliding window" step is set to one.

For example `"abcdab".sliding(2).toSet` will provide the result you are looking for.

In Scala 2.13 `String.sliding` is deprecated. The correct solution at Scala 2.13 will be:

```
"abcdab".toSeq.sliding(2).map(_.unwrap).toSet
```

- [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/hs90cT66RT2xyly7I5SY5A/3) for Scala 2.13
- [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/hs90cT66RT2xyly7I5SY5A/1) for Scala 2.12